# Windows 7 doesn't connect to internet after installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, troubleshooting, internet-connection, lenovo-laptop

I recently reinstalled Windows 7 Ultimate on my Lenovo laptop because it was set to a different language prior and it was also very laggy. After the installation, everything was working except the Internet, which had a cross on it (it says no connections are available). Troubleshooting proved pointless as the moment I press "troubleshoot", it returned "Troubleshoot couldn't identify the problem". I looked through some Internet settings, including making sure that the LAN setting wasn't checked, but to no success.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you remember to install the drivers for your motherboard?  While many LAN devices use standard drivers, they may not function until after the motherboard's drivers have been installed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

After the installation there were still about 200 important updates.
Installing the updates fixed the issue and I am now able to connect to the internet.